# I am trying to build Osu! for Linux ARM64, I am having problems however

Tags: c#

Before I say anything, I have basically never touched C#. I have been doing all of this with the help of my friends, google and luck.

I have been building osu! for the Raspberry pi 5 for about 3 days now and I'm stuck on two errors (For both building in Release and Debug), one is about a "version mismatch": `"Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'osu.Game.Resources, Version=2023.1228.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest."` and the other one is about a missing dependency known as `"libveldrid-spirv"` which after researching is a .Net library which osu! uses. I can provide every step I've done so far (be advised it does look bad as I haven't finalised it and added the special touches)

I have been using the osu! version: Lazer 2023.1231.0

Running `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=true ./osu\!` and getting osu to load

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.